# Can I distinguish between a Swift class and its typealias?

Tags: swift

Is there a way to conform to `Equatable` in a way that prohibits the comparison of a class and its typealias, or at least returns false? See example below.

```
class MyClass {

    let id : Int

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

extension MyClass : Equatable {
    static func ==(rhs: MyClass, lhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return rhs.id == lhs.id
    }
}

typealias ClassAlias = MyClass

let thingOne = MyClass(id: 1)
let thingTwo = ClassAlias(id: 1)

print(thingOne == thingTwo) //prints true, but I want false or an error
```

Comment: Why? A typealias is still the same class.

Comment: You can't. Typealiases don't introduce new types and get translated to the actual type they alias compile time.

Comment: I have Categories, which consist of an id, an image, and a title. And Tags, which are the exact same model. They serve different organizational purposes, and users interact with them differently. I thought it made sense to make one an alias of the other, but I suppose I should make two different classes with the same structure instead?